# clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(ur ); causing null pointer exception

Tags: java

I got some sample code from stack overflow for a websocket client. When it tries to connect I get a exception saying null pointer.  I'm sending it a URI object, and it is not null. I doubled check to make sure the URI was correct.
Also i was not able to finde the

stack trace

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at botserver.WebsocketClientEndpoint.(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:31)
>       at cMultiWindow.testWebSocket2(cMultiWindow.java:3758)
>       at cMultiWindow.start(cMultiWindow.java:1363)
>       at cStart.main(cStart.java:11)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at botserver.WebsocketClientEndpoint.(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:29)

Code

```
int ex=0;
URI ur;
try {
ur = new URI("wss://ws-feed.pro.coinbase.com"); 

// ur is not null
// line below causes exception
final WebsocketClientEndpoint 
clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(ur );

} catch(Exception e)
{
  ex++; 
}
```

Comment: add the stack trace

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:21)
 at cTest.main(cTest.java:22) (stack trace)

Comment: Do you have the code for the `botserver.WebsocketClientEndpoint` constructor?

Comment: Is `WebsocketClientEndpoint` from a librabry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jar file i was using for javax did not have getWebSocketContainer(); emplamented so it would return a null.
I used a new jar file called try-standalone-client-1.9.jar 
problem fixed :)