# getting message "This element nether has attached source code or javadoc" could not having sourc e code cause promgram to crash?

Tags: java

Hi I posted a message early because the following line causes a null exception

`WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();`

**Code**

```
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

    Session userSession = null;
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;

    public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
        try {
            // crashes hear
             WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:21)
    at cTest.main(cTest.java:22)

when I scroll on top of WebSocketContainer it gives the message
   "This element nether has attached source code or javadoc" 

could not having source code   cause program to crash?
 since it has no attached source code code that cause the exception?
 for the javax lib I got the jar file called websocket-api from the tomcat installation
```

Comment: No it won't cause a crash.

Comment: The warning is just your IDE telling you it can't show you the source code or doc. The compiled code is available though, otherwise you'd get and `error: cannot find symbol [...] <classname>` or `error: package <packagename> does not exist`

Comment: The NPE is thrown from your own class, which means `ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer()` returns `null` and the next line tries to do `null.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);` which causes the NPE.

Comment: Why ask a new question instead of adding more info to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257536/clientendpoint-new-websocketclientendpointur-causing-null-pointer-exceptio)?

Comment: Thank you Aaron for the insight, now I have to figure out why it is returning a null